# How to get rid of the perspective effect in a 3D graphics

Tags: graphics3d, chemistry

I have plotted a figure of MoS2 crytal structure. But the actual output looks like the spheres are not in the correct position due to the perspective effect.

I obtained the correct position figure by setting the `ViewPoint` to `Infinity`. But when I rotate the figure, the infinity effect fails and the perspective effect takes place again.

[image: before and after rotation]

I was wondering if there is a way to get rid of the perspective effect when you draw a graphic?
Thank you.

Here is my code

```
a0 = 1; ceng = 1; znn =3*ceng; ynn = 5; xnn = 5; a1 = 2; cznn = 3; hh = 2;
p1[θ_] := RotationTransform[θ, {0, 0, 1}];
posx1 = (nx1 - 1) a0 + ((ny1 - 1) a0)/2 + (Mod[nz1 - 1, 3] a0)/2;
posy1 = Sqrt[3]/2 (ny1 - 1) a0 + (Sqrt[3] Mod[nz1 - 1, 3] a0)/6;
posz1 = Sqrt[3]/2 (nz1 - 1) a0 + Floor[(nz1 - 1)/3] a0;
sinpq2 = Transpose[Table[{posx1, posy1, posz1}, {ny1, ynn}, {nz1, znn}, {nx1, -xnn, 0}]];
rr = 0.3 a0;
tom2 = 
  Table[
    Graphics3D[{If[Mod[cc, 3] == 2, Pink, Yellow], Sphere[sinpq2[[cc, bb, aa]], rr]}], 
    {aa, xnn}, {bb, ynn}, {cc,znn}];
Show[tom2, 
  Axes -> False, 
  BoxStyle -> Directive[Orange, Opacity[0]],  
  BoxRatios -> Automatic, 
  PlotRange -> All, 
  Background -> Black,  
  ViewPoint -> {0, 0, ∞}]
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Switching among view points in a Manipulate expression](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/28578/switching-among-view-points-in-a-manipulate-expression)

Comment: this might be a duplicate of [3D plots with parallel projection](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13801/3d-plots-with-parallel-projection) - not quite sure what's required

Comment: Try `ViewPoint -> {0, 0, Dynamic[∞, None]}`

Comment: @cormullion closely related because OP here want to rotate an object.

Comment: @kuba Ah yes, I see - as soon as you start to rotate the viewpoint changes back to perspective. m_goldberg's solution doesn't work for me either...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Maybe this will help a little (adapting documentation exaple for `Slider2D`):

```
 DynamicModule[{p = {2 π, 0}},
   Row @ {Slider2D[Dynamic[p], {{2 Pi, 0}, {0, Pi}}],
          Plot3D[Exp[-(x^2 + y^2)], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, 
            ImageSize -> {700, 700}, PlotRange -> All, ViewAngle -> .0015,
            ViewPoint -> Dynamic[1200 {Cos[p[[1]]] Sin[p[[2]]], 
                                       Sin[p[[1]]] Sin[p[[2]]], 
                                       Cos[p[[2]]]}
                         ]
          ]   
   }]
```

[image]

Notice that for parallel projection (like here) box edges **do not seem to be parallel but they are** and for default *Mathematica* display they **are not but they look parallel**

Comment: +1 Cool! Very smooth control of object. Far better than the Mathematica default, in my view.

Comment: It means I upvoted your entry.

Comment: @DavidCarraher I thought so but something strange is happening to my rep and inbox lately. Good luck with Your project.

Comment: @Kuba This is awesome!! But can't help complaining about mma.

Comment: @Kuba Could you please kindly comment the following. I cannot catch, where is in your code the part controlling the fact that the box edges are parallel? For the first glance it just looks like simply a nice rotation, though I see, indeed, the trick with the box edges you mention in the bottom of your answer. So, how did you achieve that?

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch It's only about setting a distant ViewPoint and my last remark is about strange feeling those parallel edges make for used to perspective eyes (at least for me).

Answer (score 9):

I think the only way to do this is by dynamically reseting the [`ViewMatrix`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ViewMatrix.html) to be an [orthographic projection](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ViewMatrix.html#464375084).  It was beyond my ability, patience, or inclination to figure how to decompose the `ViewMatrix` that is created when the graphic is moved into the components `ViewPoint`, `ViewVertical`, etc.  It seemed to me that the front end usually make a discontinuous jump from the view point in the orthographic projection to the initial view point in rotated graphic.  Discouraged by this apparent behavior, I opted for a hybrid solution.

I used an ordinary `Graphics3D` with `Dynamic` view properties and used `Inset` to insert the graphics `tom2` into it.  The view properties of the outer `Graphics3D` are used to compute a corresponding orthographic projection `ViewMatrix` to be used to display the graphics `tom2`.  So the mouse rotates the outer graphics and the code rotates the inset `tom2` in the same way.  The only difference is that `tom2` is projected orthographically instead of perspectively.

To do this, I used and adapted code from [Heike](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/46)
in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3528/extract-values-for-viewmatrix-from-a-graphics3d/5764#5764)
and
[Alexey Popkov](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/280)
in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18034/how-to-get-the-real-plotrange-of-graphics-with-geometrictransformations-in-it/18040#18040).
I needed Alexey Popkov's `completePlotRange` because `AbsoluteOptions` would not return the actual plot range.

```
(* Heike *)
theta[v1_] := ArcTan[v1[[3]], Norm[v1[[;; 2]]]];
phi[v1_] := If[Norm[v1[[;; 2]]] > .0001, ArcTan[v1[[1]], v1[[2]]], 0];
alpha[vert_, v1_] := ArcTan[{-Sin[phi[v1]], Cos[phi[v1]], 0}.vert, 
                             Cross[v1/Norm[v1], {-Sin[phi[v1]], Cos[phi[v1]], 0}].vert];
tt[v1_, vert_, center_, r_, scale_] := TransformationMatrix[
   RotationTransform[-alpha[vert/scale, v1], {0, 0, 1}] .
   RotationTransform[-theta[v1], {0, 1, 0}] .
   RotationTransform[-phi[v1], {0, 0, 1}] .
   ScalingTransform[r {1, 1, 1}] .
   TranslationTransform[-center]];

(* orthographic projection *)
pp = N@{{1, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 0, 1}, {0, 0, -1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 2}};

(* Alexey Popkov *)
completePlotRange[plot : (_Graphics | _Graphics3D)] := 
 Quiet@Last@
   Last@Reap[
     Rasterize[
      Show[plot, Axes -> True, Ticks -> (Sow[{##}] &), 
       DisplayFunction -> Identity], ImageResolution -> 1]]

(* OP *)
a0 = 1; ceng = 1; znn = 3*ceng; ynn = 5; xnn = 5; a1 = 2; cznn = 3; hh = 2;
p1[θ_] := RotationTransform[θ, {0, 0, 1}];
posx1 = (nx1 - 1) a0 + ((ny1 - 1) a0)/2 + (Mod[nz1 - 1, 3] a0)/2;
posy1 = Sqrt[3]/2 (ny1 - 1) a0 + (Sqrt[3] Mod[nz1 - 1, 3] a0)/6;
posz1 = Sqrt[3]/2 (nz1 - 1) a0 + Floor[(nz1 - 1)/3] a0;
sinpq2 = Transpose[Table[{posx1, posy1, posz1},
                         {ny1, ynn}, {nz1, znn}, {nx1, -xnn, 0}]];
rr = 0.3 a0;
(* updated - switched Graphics3D and Table, adjusted options *)
tom2 = Graphics3D[
   Table[{If[Mod[cc, 3] == 2, Pink, Yellow], Sphere[N@sinpq2[[cc, bb, aa]], rr]},
         {aa, xnn}, {bb, ynn}, {cc, znn}],
   Axes -> False, BoxStyle -> Directive[Orange, Opacity[1]], 
   BoxRatios -> Automatic, Background -> Black];

(* adapted from Heike *)
bb = completePlotRange@tom2;
scale = 1/Abs[#1 - #2] & @@@ bb;
center = Mean /@ bb;
vv = {Flatten[Differences /@ bb] + center, center};
v1 = (vv[[1]] - center);
vert = {0, 0, 1} - {0, 0, 1}.v1 v1;
viewAngle = 2 ArcCot[2.];

(* final graphic *)
Graphics3D[{},
 Epilog -> Inset[
   Show[tom2, 
        ViewMatrix ->
          Dynamic@{tt[v1, vert, center, Cot[viewAngle/2]/Norm[v1], scale], pp},
        PlotRange -> bb],
   Center, Center, 1],
 ViewAngle    -> Dynamic[viewAngle], 
 ViewVector   -> Dynamic[vv, (vv = #; center = vv[[2]]; v1 = vv[[1]] - center) &], 
 ViewVertical -> Dynamic[vert],
 SphericalRegion -> True, PlotRange -> bb, Boxed -> False]
```

Output after manual rotation:

[image]
[image]

Comment: I'm sure you don't want to look at this code again... I'm seeing this error: http://i.stack.imgur.com/cHgNh.png

Comment: I think it works now.

Answer (score 5):

I just found the simplest solution.

Don't set `ViewPoint` to infinity!!! Just set it any number large enough, the effect will equivalent to setting to infinity.

Try for example the following

```
ListPointPlot3D[Tuples[Range[10], 3], BoxRatios -> Automatic, 
 ViewPoint -> {0, 0, 1000}]
```

for your example just change `ViewPoint -> {0, 0, ∞}` to `ViewPoint -> {0, 0, 1000}` or any number large than 1000 as you wish.

You'll be amazed at how simple it is to get rid of perspective. Rotate freely! : )

Comment: Works for me, very cool!

Answer (score 4):

Mathematica Version 11.2 affords the new option : `ViewProjection-> "Orthographic"`.

It seems to do the job, but I can't test the interacitvity because I have only access to Mathematica 11.2 in the cloud (in the "Wolfram Development Platform").

So instead of interacting, I have set `ViewPoint -> {0, 0, 3}` in your example.

Here are the results :

```
a0 = 1; ceng = 1; znn =3*ceng; ynn = 5; xnn = 5; a1 = 2; cznn = 3; hh = 2;
p1[\[Theta]_] := RotationTransform[\[Theta], {0, 0, 1}];
posx1 = (nx1 - 1) a0 + ((ny1 - 1) a0)/2 + (Mod[nz1 - 1, 3] a0)/2;
posy1 = Sqrt[3]/2 (ny1 - 1) a0 + (Sqrt[3] Mod[nz1 - 1, 3] a0)/6;
posz1 = Sqrt[3]/2 (nz1 - 1) a0 + Floor[(nz1 - 1)/3] a0;
sinpq2 = Transpose[Table[{posx1, posy1, posz1}, {ny1, ynn}, {nz1, znn}, {nx1, -xnn, 0}]];
rr = 0.3 a0;
tom2 = 
  Table[
    Graphics3D[{If[Mod[cc, 3] == 2, Pink, Yellow], Sphere[sinpq2[[cc, bb, aa]], rr]}], 
    {aa, xnn}, {bb, ynn}, {cc,znn}];


Show[tom2, 
  Axes -> False, 
  BoxStyle -> Directive[Orange, Opacity[0]],  
  BoxRatios -> Automatic, 
  PlotRange -> All, 
  Background -> Black,  
  ViewPoint -> {0, 0, 3}]


Show[tom2, 
  Axes -> False, 
  BoxStyle -> Directive[Orange, Opacity[0]],  
  BoxRatios -> Automatic, 
  PlotRange -> All, 
  Background -> Black,  
  ViewPoint -> {0, 0, 3},
  ViewProjection-> "Orthographic" (* <--- Here is the modification *)
  ]
```

[image]

It seems to work fine.

Comment: I confirm it works fine, including interactivity, in normal desktop version of Mathematica 11.2 (Linux x86).

Answer (score 3):

Combining some of the ideas here and elsewhere, this appears to produce a parallel projection:

```
tr = TransformationMatrix[
RescalingTransform[{{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}, {-3/2, 5/2}}]];
p = {{1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1}};
DynamicModule[{vm = {tr, p}, vp = {0, 0, 100}},
 tom2 = Table[
   Graphics3D[{If[Mod[cc, 3] == 2, Pink, Yellow], 
     Sphere[sinpq2[[cc, bb, aa]], rr]}, 
     ViewMatrix -> Dynamic[vm], 
     ViewPoint -> Dynamic[vp]], 
  {aa, xnn}, {bb, ynn}, {cc, znn}];
 Show[tom2, 
   Axes -> False, 
   BoxStyle -> Directive[Orange, Opacity[0]],
   BoxRatios -> Automatic, 
   PlotRange -> All, 
   Background -> Black]]
```

which you can test by looking at the columns of spheres end on - there's hardly any perspective at all:

[image: a load of balls]

Comment: Rats, I was doing the same thing.  If you change the opacity on the box, it's easier to see it's slightly off.  The initial settings a reset on rotating the graphics to a perpective that is fairly far away.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Yes, it all seems more difficult than necessary. A nice `ViewMode -> Cabinet` or `Cavalier` would be cool. (Anyone know those? :)

Comment: @cormullion The lattice changes size when rotating, can the size be fixed?