# Set defaults for ViewPoint and AxesLabel

Tags: plotting

Instead of adding `AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}` every time to code in order that the axes appear, how can I make *Mathematica* display the axes by default?

Also, how can I get *Mathematica* to display the axes, by default, as they are shown in the following image? I want to obviate having to by rotate my images manually every time *Mathematica* makes its initial display.

[image]

Comment: Look up `SetOptions` and `ViewPoint` or `ViewMatrix`. And in my book your coordinate system is right-handed.

Comment: [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:3D_Cartesian_Coodinate_Handedness.jpg) agrees with your book, @yvesklett.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I´ll bite after some deliberation, since this might actually be useful for future searches:

```
SetOptions[Graphics3D, Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}, 
  Boxed -> False, ViewPoint -> 2 {1, 0, 0}, ViewVertical -> {0, 0, 1}];

Graphics3D[Arrow[{0 #, #}] & /@ IdentityMatrix[3]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You will have to choose your `ViewPoint` or `ViewMatrix` parameters according to the kind of projection you are after (I suspect you are after some kind of [parallel projection](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/28600/131)). The placing of the actual `Axes` is a bit idiosyncratic and not always what one would expect, but you can roll your own axes if you want to.