# How to set desired view in 3D?

Tags: graphics3d

Consider very simple 3D object: `Tube` from `{0,0,0}` to `{1,2,3}`. I want to see projection to `X-Z` plane. My first attempt is:

```
Show[Graphics3D[Tube[{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 2, 3}}]],
  Axes -> {True, False, True}, ViewPoint -> {0, ∞, 0}, Boxed -> False]
```

And I want `Z` axis being in horizontal direction, so I have to manually rotate by `Pi/2` clockwise. Finally I get this:

[image]

You see not ideal alignment of axes, but this is what I want to get.

Another attempt is as follows:

```
Show[Graphics3D[
  GeometricTransformation[Tube[{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 2, 3}}], 
   Composition[ReflectionTransform[{1, 0, 0}], 
    RotationTransform[ -π/2, {0, 1, 0}]]]], 
 Axes -> {True, False, True}, Boxed -> False, ViewPoint -> Front]
```

With this I can get desired view, but picture is very different from first one:

[image]

So, the question is: how to get `X-Z` projection and `Z` axis being horizontal?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you seen `ViewVertical`?

Comment: @J.M., yes, I know about `ViewVertical`. I don't know how to use that in my case. If I replace in first code `ViewPoint->{0, \[Infinity], 0}` with `ViewVertical->{0,1,0}` I get the same result: projection to `X-Z` plane and `Z` axis is vertical. I need `Z` axis being horizontal. Please, explain how to use `ViewVertical` option?

Comment: Try `ViewVertical -> {1, 0, 0}` ("make $x$ vertical").

Comment: OK, adding `ViewVertical->{1,0,0}` to my first code solves the problem. Many thanks to @J.M.! My confusion was that if I set `ViewPoint` I'll have "plane" picture (projection to some plane) and I can't apply `ViewVertical` (I thought it has sense in 3D only).

Comment: Another aside observation of MMA strange behaviour. If in fresh notebook I execute my original first code, this gives me some picture of plane projection. Let's denote this first In[] and Out] cells. Now in the oroginal first input cell I change `ViewPoint->{0, \[Infinity], 0}` with `ViewVertical->{0,1,0}` and execute this cell. The picture in output doesn't change. If I delete Out[] cell and run In[] again I'll have 3D view with `Y` axis being vertical, as it should be. Why MMA doesn't replace Out[] after In[] was edited?

Comment: Sorry for typos in previous comment, unfortunately I can't edit my own comments.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/28600/how-to-get-rid-of-the-perspective-effect-in-a-3d-graphics

Answer (score 2):

Answer from a comment:

> No, as J.M. proposed in his comment this does exctly what I need:
>
> ```
> Show[Graphics3D[Tube[{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 2, 3}}]], Axes -> {True, False, True}, 
>       ViewPoint -> {0, ∞, 0}, ViewVertical ->{1,0,0}, Boxed -> False]
> ```
>
> does what I need and what is shown in my first picture. – [Alx](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/35574/alx) [Dec 16 '16 at 10:43](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/133632/how-to-set-desired-view-in-3d#comment360651_133651)

Answer (score 0):

Will this do:

```
     Show[Graphics3D[
  Rotate[Tube[{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 2, 3}}], {{0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 0}}]], 
 Axes -> {True, False, True}, AxesLabel -> {"z", "y", "x"}, 
 ViewPoint -> {1.5, -100, 0.5}, Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

??

Comment: No, as J.M. proposed in his comment this does exctly what I need: `Show[Graphics3D[Tube[{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 2, 3}}]], Axes -> {True, False, True}, ViewPoint -> {0, \[Infinity], 0}, ViewVertical ->{1,0,0}, Boxed -> False]` does what I need and what is shown in my first picture.