# Project ParametricPlot3D onto 2D plane

Tags: graphics3d, plotting

I have this `ParametricPlot3D`:

[image]

generated by this code:

```
x[α_, β_, γ_, t_] :=
  Sin[α] Cos[β] Cos[γ] Cos[t] + Sin[α] Sin[γ] Sin[t] - Cos[α] Sin[β] Cos[γ];
y[α_, β_, γ_, t_] := 
  Sin[α] Cos[β] Sin[γ] Cos[t] + Sin[α] Cos[γ] Sin[t] + Cos[α] Sin[β] Sin[γ];
z[α_, β_, t_] := 
 Sin[α] Sin[β] Cos[t] + Cos[α] Cos[β]

α = π/3;
β = +π/3;
γ = 0;

Show[
  ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[u] Sin[v], Cos[u] Cos[v], Sin[u]}, {u, 0, π}, {v, -π/2, π/2},
    Mesh -> None, 
    PlotStyle -> Opacity[.25, Blue], PlotPoints -> 80, 
    MaxRecursion -> 4, 
    ExclusionsStyle -> ({Directive[Opacity[1], Thick, Red]}), 
    Boxed -> False, Axes -> False], 
  ParametricPlot3D[Normalize[{x[α, β, γ, t], y[α, β, γ, t], z[α, β, t]}], {t, 0, π}], 
  ParametricPlot3D[Normalize[{-x[α, β, γ, -t], -y[α, β, γ, -t], z[α, β, -t]}], {t, 2 π, π}],
  Graphics3D[{PointSize[0.025], Point[{0, 0, 1}]}],
  ViewPoint -> Front]
```

--

I want to project it down to a 2D plane so that I see something like this:

[image]

Any ideas?

**EDIT**:

The result of

```
Plot[Normalize[{x[α, β, γ, t], y[α, β, γ, t], z[α, β, t]}][[ ;; 2]], {t, 0, 2 π}]
```

is

[image]

**EDIT 2**

Trying to set $z=0$ in the parameterisation:

```
Show[
  ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[u] Sin[v], Cos[u] Cos[v], Sin[u]}, {u, 0, π}, {v, -π/2, π/2},
    Mesh -> None, 
    PlotStyle -> Opacity[.25, Blue], PlotPoints -> 80, 
    MaxRecursion -> 4, 
    ExclusionsStyle -> ({Directive[Opacity[1], Thick, Red]}), 
    Boxed -> False, Axes -> False], 
  ParametricPlot3D[Normalize[{x[α, β, γ, t], y[α, β, γ, t], 0}], {t, 0, π}], 
  ParametricPlot3D[Normalize[{-x[α, β, γ, -t], -y[α, β, γ, -t], 0}], {t, 2 π, π}], 
  Graphics3D[{PointSize[0.025], Point[{0, 0, 1}]}],
  ViewPoint -> Front]
```

[image]

Comment: You haven't included the definitions of `x`, `y`, and `z`, so we cannot reproduce. In principle, though, couldn't you just plot `Normalize[{x[α, β, γ, t], y[α, β, γ, t], z[α, β, t]}][[;;2]]`?

Comment: Ah, sorry. I tried yes, I included what I see. I just want it to round as it is a projection

Comment: Just set $z=0$ in your parameterization.

Comment: Tried that too. See EDIT 2.

Comment: use `ParametricPlot` with `Normalize[{x[α, β, γ, t], y[α, β, γ, t], z[α, β, t]}][[;;2]]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that due to the use of `Normalize`, you may get wrong results if you just substitute z with 0. Also, the 3D plot only shows part where $z>0$, so:

```
Show[
  ParametricPlot[{Cos[u], Sin[u]}, {u, 0, 2 π}], 
  ParametricPlot[Most@Normalize[{x[α, β, γ, t], y[α, β, γ, t], z[α, β, t]}],
    {t, 0, π}, 
    RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, t}, z[α, β, t] > 0]],
  ParametricPlot[Most@Normalize[{-x[α, β, γ, -t], -y[α, β, γ, -t], z[α, β, -t]}],
    {t, π, 2 π}, 
    RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, t}, z[α, β, -t] > 0]]
 ]
```

[image]

**EDIT**

To put this in a 3D plot, try this idea:

```
p1 = Flatten[{Most[Normalize[{x[\[Alpha], \[Beta], \[Gamma], t], y[\[Alpha], \[Beta], \[Gamma], t], z[\[Alpha], \[Beta], t]}]], 0}];
p2 = Flatten[{Most[Normalize[{-x[\[Alpha], \[Beta], \[Gamma], -t], -y[\[Alpha], \[Beta], \[Gamma], -t], z[\[Alpha], \[Beta], -t]}]], 0}];
Show[ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[u], Sin[u], 0}, {u, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, 
  Axes -> False, Boxed -> False], 
 ParametricPlot3D[p1, {t, 0, \[Pi]}, 
  RegionFunction -> 
   Function[{xc, yc, zc, t}, z[\[Alpha], \[Beta], t] > 0]],
 ParametricPlot3D[p2, {t, \[Pi], 2 \[Pi]}, 
  RegionFunction -> 
   Function[{xc, yc, zc, t}, z[\[Alpha], \[Beta], -t] > 0]],
 Graphics3D[{PointSize[0.025], Point[{0, 0, 0}]}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I am trying to put it in a 3D plot though so that I can change the angle of view. I tried `Show[ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[u], Sin[u], 0}, {u, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, 
  Axes -> False, Boxed -> False], 
 ParametricPlot3D[
  Most@Normalize@{x[\[Alpha], \[Beta], \[Gamma], t], 
     y[\[Alpha], \[Beta], \[Gamma], t], z[\[Alpha], \[Beta], t]}, {t, 
   0, \[Pi]}, 
  RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, t}, z[\[Alpha], \[Beta], t] > 0]],
 Graphics3D[{PointSize[0.025], Point[{0, 0, 0}]}]]` but it doesn't work.. any ideas?

Comment: @SuperCiocia see my edits above.

Answer (score 5):

Try `ViewPoint -> Top` instead of `ViewPoint -> Front` in your plot:

[image]

Parallel projection:  `ViewVector -> {{0, 0, 1000}, {0, 0, -1}}`:

[image]

Comment: note due to perspective /view point, the projection obtained this way may look slightly different than what one wants. https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/28600/how-to-get-rid-of-the-perspective-effect-in-a-3d-graphics

Comment: That's ok, you have to adapt the viewpoint far away ( `ViewVector-> {100{0,0,1},{0,0,-1}}`)to get "parallel projection!